# Can an ERC-20 have more than 18 decimals?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, evm, decimals, floating-point

I've seen most tokens use 18 decimals and USDC use 6 decimals.  Is it possible for a token to have over 18?

Comment: I would say 255 since decimals() of in IERC20 interface is defined as uint8 (ref https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum amount of token that a ERC-20 contract can mind (according to the specification) is the max of uint256, which is (2 ** 256)-1 ≈ 10 ** 77. And the decimal variable merely mentions the number of decimal places to be used while displaying the amount on a UI. Theoretically, you could use any decimal. As long as the decimal is less than 77, you'll have a whole number part (mantissa). For example, if you have 18 decimals, the max value you can have is (2 ** 256-1)/10 ** 18 ≈ 10 ** 59. Most ERC-20 tokens use 18 so as to stay comparable to other tokens in terms of supply.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm working on alternative EVM blockchain and I noticed some tokens had 24 decimals.  It was breaking my contracts so I'm updating them for >18 decimal support.