# Covert ERC-20 tokens with different decimals to amount to Wei

Tags: web3js, javascript

For example when I want to send `ERC-20` tokens to a contract, I specify the amount in Wei
So I have to convert `34678393` tokens to Wei. But it only works ok with tokens that have 18 decimals

I'm using web3's `toWei()` function like this

```
  const sendTokens = async (amount)  => {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract("ADDRESS",ABI)
    await contract.sendTokens(web3.utils.toWei(amount))
  }
```

How can I convert tokens amount with different decimals to Wei?

Comment: See [evm-bn](https://github.com/paulrberg/evm-bn).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, yes, you can.

Just make sure that you send the correct weis to the token contract. The token contract should have a function to get how many decimals it uses.

If you know that the token contract uses 3 decimals, then you can convert your `amount` `toWei` passing a `kwei` param. If it uses 6 decimals, then `mwei`, etc. Check the following code and read the comments:

```js
// 34678393_000 the last 3 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 3 decimals, then use `kwei`.
const result2 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "kwei");
console.log("34678393 to wei (kwei): ", result2);

// 34678393_000000 the last 6 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 6 decimals, then use `mwei`.
const result3 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "mwei");

console.log("34678393 to wei (mwei): ", result3);

// 34678393_000000000 the last 9 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 9 decimals, then use `gwei`.
const result4 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "gwei");

console.log("34678393 to wei (gwei): ", result4);

// 34678393_000000000000 the last 12 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 12 decimals, then use `szabo`.
const result5 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "szabo");

console.log("34678393 to wei (szabo): ", result5);

// 34678393_000000000000000 the last 15 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 15 decimals, then use `finney`.
const result6 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "finney");

console.log("34678393 to wei (finney): ", result6);

// 34678393_000000000000000000 the last 18 zeros are the decimals
const result = web3.utils.toWei("34678393");

console.log("34678393 to wei (ether): ", result);

// 34678393_000000000000000000000 the last 21 zeros could be used as decimals. If your token uses 21 decimals, then use `kether`.
const result7 = web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "kether");

console.log("34678393 to wei (kether): ", result7);

// Use `mether` for 25 decimals
// Use `gether` fo 26 28 decimals
// Use tether for 31 decimals

// For other decimals, you will probably need to implement your own logic or find a library that handles other decimals.
```

It prints something like:

```
34678393 to wei (kwei):  34678393000
34678393 to wei (mwei):  34678393000000
34678393 to wei (gwei):  34678393000000000
34678393 to wei (szabo):  34678393000000000000
34678393 to wei (finney):  34678393000000000000000
34678393 to wei (ether):  34678393000000000000000000
34678393 to wei (kether):  34678393000000000000000000000
```

Here is the docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-utils.html?highlight=toWei#towei

If you are calling a token that uses 3 decimals, then the last 3 digits of the number you send will be treated as the decimals.

So, if you want to send `34678393` tokens with no decimals, then you need to append 3 zeros, because if you don't, then the token will treat the number `34678393` as `34678.393`. Which may not be what you want.

That's you you need to either append the 3 zeros or use the `web3.utils.toWei("34678393", "kwei")` function, so it returns `34678393000` and we can send it to the token, indicating that the amount does not have any decimal values.

Comment: Thanks that's a great answer. I have a question though, What about tokens that have different decimals like 5 or one and 7? according to this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118896/can-an-erc-20-have-more-than-18-decimals#:~:text=Theoretically%2C%20you%20could%20use%20any,tokens%20in%20terms%20of%20supply. 

we could use any decimals as long as it is less than 77

Comment: Simple add 5 ir 7 zeros at the end of it.

Comment: But what about double values like 0.3?

Comment: When I add zeros according to decimals in 0.3, if I'm not wrong it throws an error like `wrong input value`