# Any actively used ERC20 tokens that have more than 18 decimals?

Tags: erc-20, decimals

Any examples? I'm wondering if there's a strong reason to support tokens with more than 18 decimals.

Please note it's related to, but different from the question "[Can an ERC-20 have more than 18 decimals?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118896/can-an-erc-20-have-more-than-18-decimals)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, no.

18 decimals is sufficient for most tokens, so most tokens fall into that category. Some tokens may choose to use more or less decimal places but that's not exactly standard. If your question is if your trading application should support a broader decimal range, the short answer is, it depends on what your application purpose is, more new age and "wild-west" exchanges may choose to do so but most stable and well known exchanges support more restricted decimal ranges.